# Failing to create list for comparison

Tags: python, list

I have problems in Python.

```
def Square_Check (arr1, arr2):
    if(len(arr1) != len(arr2)):
        return false;
    Frequency_Counter1 = ()
    Frequency_Counter2 = ()
    for value in Frequency_Counter1 :
        Frequency_Counter[value] = (Frequency_Counter[value] or 0)+1
    for value in Frequency_Counter :
        Frequency_Counter[value] = (Frequency_Counter[value] or 0)+1
    print(Frequency_Counter)
    print(Frequency_Counter)

    for key in Frequency_Counter:
        if !(key in Frequency_Counter):
            return false
        if(Frequency_Counter[key**2] != Frequency_Counter[key]):
            return false
    return true

Square_Check([3,2], [2,3])
```

The first one is `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'len'`. The second one is that `if !(key in Frequency_Counter):` is not valid.

If I have `Square_Check([3,2], [4,9])`, Frequency_Counter1 is supposed to store 3 and 2 (one time each) and then I compare it to [4,9] to see if the squares of 2 and 3 are stored in arr2.

With the frequency counters, I'm supposed to get the occurrence of every character in the lists.

Here is what I should get:

```
Square_Check([3,2], [2,3])
{3: 1, 2: 1}
{2: 1, 3: 1}
False

Square_Check([3,2], [4,9])
{3: 1, 2: 1}
{4: 1, 9: 1}
False

Square_Check([3,2], [2,9])
{3: 1, 2: 1}
{2: 1, 9: 1}
```

I should get True if second list contains squared values of items in first list.

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which line gives ```AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'len'```?

Comment: The second line.

Comment: The 2nd line doesn't throw any error, please check

Answer (score 1):

```html
def Square_Check (arr1, arr2):
    if(len(arr1) != len(arr2)):
        return false;
    freqCount1 = {}
    freqCount2 = {}
    for value in arr1:
         freqCount1[value] = _getDictValue(freqCount1, value)+1
    for value in arr2:
         freqCount2[value] = _getDictValue(freqCount2, value)+1
    print(freqCount1)
    print(freqCount2)
    for key in freqCount1.keys():
        if (freqCount1[key] != _getDictValue(freqCount2,key**2)):
            print("False")
            return False
    print("True")
    return True
        
def _getDictValue(dict, key):
    if (not key in dict):
        return 0
    return dict[key]
    
Square_Check([3,2], [2,3])
Square_Check([3,2], [4,9])
Square_Check([3,2], [2,9])
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python booleans start with upper case (False and True).
Also, the ! symbol needs to be replaced by "not".

```html
def Square_Check (arr1, arr2):
    if(len(arr1) != len(arr2)):
        return false;
        
    arr1Sorted = sorted(arr1)
    arr2Sorted = sorted(arr2)
    for index, value in enumerate(arr1Sorted):
        if (value**2 != arr2Sorted[index]):
            print("False")
            return False
    print("True")
    return True
    
Square_Check([3,2], [4,9])
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me why the output is `()()` as if intput were empty ?

Comment: You iterate through the frequencyCounter1 and 2 which are empty. -> Nothing happens inside the "for"s. After that, you print the frequencyCounters, which continue being empty.

Comment: Lines 6 to 9 are supposed to increment the frequency counter. How am I supposed to do it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I edited it to clarify it. I would like `Square_Check([3,2], [2,3])` to return `False` (the second list doesn't store squares of the elements of the first list but `Square_Check([3,2], [4,9])` is supposed to return `True`.

Comment: Isn't there some shorter way to write it? I don't understand last part. I would like to check if the numbers in arr2 are the squares of the number in arr1. I tried to iterate through the second one to check the presence of, in this case, 9 and 4 (3^2 and 2^2).

Comment: I wanted to avoid the sort function. Isn't there a way to do it?

Comment: I posted another answer following your first approach